# @ManagedProperty("#{message}") return null

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I tried to get messages from a prop file called message.properties, I used @ManagedProperty but it's return null

my facesutil file

```
public class FacesUtils {

    /**
     * the bundle variable of type ResourceBundle
     */
    @ManagedProperty("#{message}")
    private static ResourceBundle bundle;

    public static void errorMessage(String summary, String detail) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, bundle.getString(summary), bundle.getString(detail)));
    }

// getter and setter 
}
```

and i define message in face config file

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>com.erabia.platform.erabiaen</base-name>
        <var>message</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

I used primefaces 6.0

Comment: I'm not familiar with `@ManagedProperty`, but annotations of that sort usually don't work on static fields.

Comment: And they only work in JSF managed beans  (an util class usually is not and it misses an annotation for this. And these JSF annotations are deprecated in favour of CDI ones and if you are writing a custom FacesUtils class, better look at OmniFaces.